# Display User Information from redux store on successful login

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have some issues displaying the updated redux state in my react component. Basically, what I am trying to do is to display user Information on successful login which was dispatched to redux store by the login action.

Below is my login action:

```
export function login(userDetails) {
return dispatch =>
axios.post(`${API_URL}/signin`, userDetails).then((res) => {
  const token = res.data.Token;
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  setAuthorizationToken(token);
  const decoded = jwt.decode(res.data.Token);
  dispatch({
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    user: decoded.currentUser
    });
  });
}
```

The successfully logged in user is redirected to the dashboard component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import HeaderSideBar from '../includes/header-side-bar';

class Dashboard extends Component{

render(){

     const {username} = this.props.user;

    return (
        <HeaderSideBar username={username}/>
    )
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    user: state.user
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard)
```

**My reducer:**

```
    import { AUTH_USER,
  UNAUTH_USER,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  USER_EXIST,
 SET_CURRENT_USER
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { userExist: '', error: '', message: '', user: '', 
content: '', authenticated: false };

function authReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case AUTH_USER:
  return { ...state, error: '', message: 'Successfully registered', 
authenticated: true };
case UNAUTH_USER:
  return { ...state, authenticated: false };
case AUTH_ERROR:
  return { ...state, error: action.payload };
case USER_EXIST:
  return { ...state, error: action.error };
case SET_CURRENT_USER:
  console.log(action.user);
  return { ...state, user: action.user };
default:
  return state;
  }
}

export default authReducer;
```

I want to display values from the updated state in the User dashboard. e.g username, fullname

Comment: and what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: What does your reducer look like?

Comment: @MaxMillington i have added the reducer.

Comment: Please elaborate the error that you get, without it, its very difficult to help

Comment: I am not getting any error. I need help with how to fetch the data inserted into the store in the Dashboard component. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: what is the output that you get for action.user in reducer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it contains the expected data but I need those data to be displayed in the dashboard component as props.

Comment: If you have wrapped the Routes with a Provider HOC and passed store to it, and as you have connected mapStateToProps already to the component this.props.user should show you the data in dashboard render

Comment: Can you post how you are doing the `<Provider`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to directly use the props in your Dashboard component, like,

`render(){
    return (
        <HeaderSideBar username={this.props.user}/>
    )
 }`